# SSAS multidimensional cube - parallel processing of partitions

Tags: ssas

I have one multidimensional cube that have just one fact table with 2 partitions. I run the processing and when I looked in Process Progress window, I saw that only one partition has been processed, and other is waiting. And somehow I expected that it will process both partitions in parallel.

Am I missing something, or it just works that way by default. Should I do something to force parallel processing in order to speed it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you sending the processing request?  Try using an XMLA script with the `Parallel` option as outlined below.

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Parallel>
        <Process>
            <Object>
                <DatabaseID>Your Cube</DatabaseID>
                <CubeID>Your Cube</CubeID>
                <MeasureGroupID>Fact Table</MeasureGroupID>
                <PartitionID>Fact_Table_Partition_1</PartitionID>
            </Object>
            <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
        </Process>
        <Process>
            <Object>
                <DatabaseID>Your Cube</DatabaseID>
                <CubeID>Your Cube</CubeID>
                <MeasureGroupID>Fact Table</MeasureGroupID>
                <PartitionID>Fact_Table_Partition_2</PartitionID>
            </Object>
            <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
        </Process>
    </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

Comment: I have just right clicked on database and clicked Process option, so I suppose that this is a default behavior when you run processing this way? This is the command that is auto generated: <Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>MyDatabase</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>

Comment: The script you posted only includes the full database name as the object.  To process each partition in parallel try explicitly stating each partition (with the associated MeasureGroupID) in a separate Process command within the Parallel command as done in the answer I posted.